# django-avatar // not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

https://django-avatar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Django returns "not enough values to unpack (Expected 2, got 1) when trying to open this html template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load account %} {% load avatar_tags %}

{% block content %}

<div style="border: 2px solid #ffffff; text-align:center">
    <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    <div>

        {% avatar user %}

        <a href="{% url 'avatar_change' %}">Change your avatar</a>
        
    </div>

    <div>
        <p>Welcome back, {% user_display user %}</p>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

and highlights "`{% avatar user %}`"

Here's the traceback: https://dpaste.com/B7EX28LNB

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/

Django Version: 4.2.4
Python Version: 3.11.5
Installed Applications:
['yt2b2',
 'home',
 'dashboard',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'embed_video',
 'avatar',
 'allauth',
 'allauth.account',
 'allauth.socialaccount']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\Pedro\Documents\GITHUB\YT2B2-new-dev\YT2B2\youtube2blog2\dashboard\templates\dashboard\dashboard.html, error at line 10
   not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
   1 : {% extends 'base.html' %}
   2 : {% load account %} {% load avatar_tags %}
   3 : 
   4 : {% block content %}
   5 : 
   6 : <div style="border: 2px solid #ffffff; text-align:center">
   7 :     <h1>Dashboard</h1>
   8 :     <div>
   9 : 
   10 :          {% avatar user %} 
   11 : 
   12 :         <a href="{% url 'avatar_change' %}">Change your avatar</a>
   13 :         
   14 :     </div>
   15 : 
   16 :     <div>
   17 :         <p>Welcome back, {% user_display user %}</p>
   18 :     </div>
   19 : </div>
   20 : 


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py", line 23, in _wrapper_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\Documents\GITHUB\YT2B2-new-dev\YT2B2\youtube2blog2\dashboard\views.py", line 10, in dashboard
    return render(request, 'dashboard/dashboard.html', {})
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 24, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 157, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 63, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in render
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 1005, in <listcomp>
    return SafeString("".join([node.render_annotated(context) for node in self]))
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 966, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\template\library.py", line 237, in render
    output = self.func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\avatar\templatetags\avatar_tags.py", line 48, in avatar
    url = avatar_url(user, width, height)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\avatar\utils.py", line 72, in cached_func
    result = func(user, width or default_size, height, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\avatar\templatetags\avatar_tags.py", line 21, in avatar_url
    avatar_url = provider.get_avatar_url(user, width, height)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Pedro\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\avatar\providers.py", line 77, in get_avatar_url
    _, domain = email.split(b"@")
    ^^^^^^^^^

Exception Type: ValueError at /dashboard/
Exception Value: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Any suggestions of how to fix this? Everything is setup properly.

I'm also using allauth if there's some kind of conflict.

I tried redoing the documentation setup, still won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the sources of django-avatar, your error came from this line: https://github.com/jazzband/django-avatar/blob/main/avatar/providers.py#L77

Did you change the value of `settings.AVATAR_GRAVATAR_FIELD` ? If yes, what is the value of this field for the user you tried to display an avatar. If not, what is the value of field `email` (the default for `settings.AVATAR_GRAVATAR_FIELD`) for that user ?

Looking at the code :

```
def get_avatar_url(cls, user, width, _height=None):
    email = getattr(user, settings.AVATAR_GRAVATAR_FIELD).encode("utf-8")
    _, domain = email.split(b"@")
```

it appear that the email value returned by `getattr(user, settings.AVATAR_GRAVATAR_FIELD)` does not contain any `@` character. This may be caused by an invalid value in your database.

See :

```
>>> email = "foo@bar.com".encode("utf-8")
>>> email.split(b"@")
[b'foo', b'bar.com']
>>> email = "invalid_email.com".encode("utf-8")
>>> email.split(b"@")
[b'invalid_email.com']
>>> _, domain = email.split(b"@")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Comment: Bingo! Thank you very much.

To any onlookers, problem was a bug with Gravatar because:

1. Site's accounts had optional email, and gravatar requires an email //

2. I hadn't set AVATAR_PROVIDERS in settings.py so Gravatar was ON by default